# Is there a supported Ember-cli addon for Polymer?

Tags: ember.js, polymer, ember-cli, polymer-1.0, ember-cli-addons

I'm fairly new to both ember-cli and polymer so bear with me.

My problem here is that I am trying to use Polymer webcomponents within my ember-cli project, however I have not been able to find an add-on or solution that works with the current versions of ember, ember-cli, and polymer that I have (all of which are the latest versions).

I have tried the ember-polymer, ember-cli-polymer, and ember-cli-polymer-toolchain addons on npm for emebr-cli and none have worked. Below is the code that I have included in my brocfile.js and I have already checked that I have installed the correct dependencies needed to vulcanize and merge the files i need.

Is there an official addon supported by the ember team, or is there simply no supported way to accomplish this. It would be a shame to not be able to include polymer's webcomponents in my projects.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var pickFiles   = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees  = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var vulcanize = require('broccoli-vulcanize');

var app = new EmberApp();

var polymer = pickFiles('bower_components/', {
  srcDir: '',
  files: [
    'polymer/polymer.html',
    'polymer/polymer.js',
    'webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'
  ],
  destDir: '/assets'
});

var polymerVulcanize = vulcanize('app', {
  input: 'elements.html',
  output: 'assets/vulcanized.html',
  csp: true,
  inline: true,
  strip: false,
  excludes: {
    imports: ["(^data:)|(^http[s]?:)|(^\/)"],
    scripts: ["(^data:)|(^http[s]?:)|(^\/)"],
    styles: ["(^data:)|(^http[s]?:)|(^\/)"]
  }
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([
  polymerVulcanize,
  polymer,
  app.toTree([polymerVulcanize])
]);
```

Comment: I am using "ember": "1.13.12", "polymer": "^1.2.4", and "webcomponentsjs": "0.7.20"

Comment: Have you added polymer assets to the index.html - like `{{content-for 'head'}}<script src="assets/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script><link rel="import" href="assets/vulcanized.html">`?

Comment: Instead of trying to use polymer with Ember, I'd suggest poking needles into your eyes. I think it would be a lot more fun.

Comment: @Knightsy I have indeed added all of the dependencies but nothing seems too work. At this point I feel like both Polymer and Ember do exactly the same thing in different ways (the only major difference being Ember Data). So at this point I think I need to really just decide which one better suits my needs at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website gives a good guide for doing it without an addon:

http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-add-polymer-to-your-ember-project/

Searching http://www.emberaddons.com/?query=polymer shows four results, [ember-cli-polymer-toolchain](https://www.npmjs.com/ember-cli-polymer-toolchain/) looks most promising with [ember-polymer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-polymer) and [ember-cli-polymer](https://www.npmjs.com/ember-cli-polymer/) also possible - although neither have been updated in the last year. Although you've tried these so I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ember-polymer](https://github.com/dunnkers/ember-polymer). I created this addon recently and am maintaining it frequently.